# Running job-dsl-plugin using jdk8 & groovy 2.4.4- java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, groovy-eclipse

I am using job-dsl plugin to automate jenkins jobs creation. Below is my maven configuration.

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<groovy.version>2.4.4</groovy.version>
<dsl.version>1.37</dsl.version>  
<groovy.eclipse.compiler.version>2.9.101</groovy.eclipse.compiler.version>
<groovy.eclipse.batch.version>2.3.7-01</groovy.eclipse.batch.version>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
         <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
         <source>${java.version}</source>
         <target>${java.version}</target>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.eclipse.compiler.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
            <version>${groovy.eclipse.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

I am using jdk8 & groovy-all 2.4.4 ,groovy-eclipse-compiler & an uber jar is generated using shade plugin. To run my scripts, I added additional classpath (under process job-dsl/advanced-settings) as target/my-uber.jar.

When I run my tests locally everything works well but on Jenkins am getting following errors

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors  during runtime and compile time for    com.salesforce.dva.pipeline.generator.model.PkgType do not match. Expected -1 but got 2
at   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(MetaClassImpl.java:1413)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:234)
```

I tried changing groovy versions (to older) & setting jdk 7 & 6 but all of them resulted in the same error.

How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins uses Groovy 1.8.x, so the Job DSL plugin also uses Groovy 1.8.x. Currently it's 1.8.9. The update to Groovy 2.x is still pending, See [JENKINS-21249](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-21249). It's recommended to use Groovy 1.8 for any Job DSL project.

Since Groovy 2.3 is the first version that officially supports Java 8 (see [Release notes for Groovy 2.3](http://www.groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-2.3.html#Groovy2.3releasenotes-OfficialsupportforrunningGroovyonJDK8)), it's recommended to use Java 7 for any Groovy 1.8 project.

Comment: Thanks for your response @daspilker. I tried using goorvy-1.8.9, java 1.7, groovy-eclipse-compiler 2.9.1-01, groovy-batch-compiler 2.3.1-01, but still got the same error "java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: the number of constructors during runtime and compile time for com.salesforce.dva.pipeline.generator.model.PkgType do not match. Expected -1 but got 2"
Do I have to change groovy-eclipse-compiler version to something else ?

Comment: My issue got resolved when I use groovy.eclipse.compiler.version -2.8.0-01 & groovy.eclipse.batch.version 2.1.8-01.
Thanks for your help @daspilker.